sap.ui.core.util.File.save file corrupted?
I want  to download in frontend an excel file that is coming from backend as OData.
The file is encoded using FM 'SCMS_BASE64_ENCODE_STR' and now I want to decode it and download it using SAPUI5.
I am trying the object sap.ui.core.util.File.save but I get a corrupted file.
Here is a test code that I created with an excel file encoded using the following site online (https://base64.guru/converter/encode/file).
openFile: function(){
            var data = "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";
         
            
            sap.ui.core.util.File.save(data, 'test', 'xlsx', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', null, null);
          
        },


This question is similar to: How can you encode/decode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks to (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-base64-to-file-in-javascript/),
I found this solution.

openFile: function(){
            var base64String = "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";
            
            const mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"; 
          
            const base64Data = base64String.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, '');
            const byteCharacters = atob(base64Data); // Decode Base64 string
            const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
    
            for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
            }
    
            const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: mimeType });
            
            sap.ui.core.util.File.save(blob, 'test', 'xlsx', mimeType, null, null);
          
        }



Where is the base64 coming from? In theory you could download the excel without any additional JS code.
